# livechat quote problem in odoo 15/16 with proxy by nginx,

Tags: nginx, odoo

on my server env : python 3.8 /odoo 16 / nginx ; visit by domain name . odoo16 working on port 8069 and gevent port 8072; no error was found when start above. all modules are running normally.
i met a question , when i used discuss module , the livechat was working good only when visit server by server IP add. if i visit domain name, the livechat only showed in notification on the right top corner icon. It can't be displayed in chat list ui. if i refreshed the page . it appeared. if i use ip visit the site. it worked. i used official recommand nginx config file. i need to correct the issue,pls help me

**1 nginx config contents:**

```
#odoo server
upstream odoo {
  server ***.com:8069;
}
upstream odoochat {
  server ***.com:8072;
}
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  ''      close;
}

# http -> https
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ***.com;
  rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name ***.com;
  proxy_read_timeout 720s;
  proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
  proxy_send_timeout 720s;

  # SSL parameters
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/***.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/***.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_session_timeout 30m;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

  # log
  access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;

  # Redirect websocket requests to odoo gevent port
  location /websocket {
    proxy_pass http://odoochat;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }

  # Redirect requests to odoo backend server
  location / {
    # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://odoo;
  }

  # common gzip
  gzip_types text/css text/scss text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
  gzip on;
}
```

2 odoo config contents:

```
[options]
addons_path = /home/odoo/odoo16/odoo/addons
admin_passwd = $pbkdf2-sha512$25000$FiLEeC/l3HtPiXGuFWLMmQ$TQNFHyiDvf9GmR5s6OFOlCr9L1EJ6.5immyQG3zmqzyXRB38ZswJkqa7.N.yKu.hvx67OUUi9YTvJBmzG075xA
csv_internal_sep = ,
data_dir = /home/odoo/.local/share/Odoo
db_host = False
db_maxconn = 64
db_name = anydb
db_password = False
db_port = False
db_sslmode = prefer
db_template = template0
db_user = False
dbfilter = 
demo = {}
email_from = False
from_filter = False
geoip_database = /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb
gevent_port = 8072
http_enable = True
http_interface = 
http_port = 8069
import_partial = 
limit_memory_hard = 2684354560
limit_memory_soft = 2147483648
limit_request = 65536
limit_time_cpu = 60
limit_time_real = 120
limit_time_real_cron = -1
list_db = True
log_db = False
log_db_level = warning
log_handler = :INFO
log_level = info
logfile = 
max_cron_threads = 2
osv_memory_age_limit = False
osv_memory_count_limit = 0
pg_path = 
pidfile = 
proxy_mode = True
reportgz = False
screencasts = 
screenshots = /tmp/odoo_tests
server_wide_modules = base,web
smtp_password = False
smtp_port = 25
smtp_server = localhost
smtp_ssl = False
smtp_ssl_certificate_filename = False
smtp_ssl_private_key_filename = False
smtp_user = False
syslog = False
test_enable = False
test_file = 
test_tags = None
transient_age_limit = 1.0
translate_modules = ['all']
unaccent = False
upgrade_path = 
websocket_keep_alive_timeout = 600
websocket_rate_limit_burst = 10
websocket_rate_limit_delay = 0.2
without_demo = True
workers = 0
x_sendfile = False
```

thks guys.

i tried and want livechat working good on proxy mode by nginx. the conversation messages could display lively.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/administration/install/deploy.html#livechat), live chat automatically takes a worker, so in your odoo.conf add a worker for it to take and nginx can use for live chat. After configuring this, the live chat will not work when you enter the instance by ip address and port.

Configuring the `odoo.conf` file

```
max_cron_threads = 1
workers = 2
```

Comment: why is max_cron_threads set to 1?  I'm having some trouble understanding.  In multi-processor mode, does max_cron_threads matter?